# Proving $1+ \frac 14 + \frac 19 + \ldots + \frac 1{n^2} \lt 2 - \frac 1n $ with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, proof-writing, induction

Prove $$1+ \frac 14 + \frac 19 + \ldots + \frac 1{n^2} \lt 2 - \frac 1n $$

What I've noticed is that it only holds $\forall n \in \mathbb Z_0 - \{1\}$ because it doesn't say in my textbook to satisty such particular conditions.

$\underline{ n= 2:} \qquad $ $1 + \frac 14 \lt 2 - \frac 12$

$\underline{I.H.:} (n=k)\qquad $ $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1{i^2} \lt 2- \frac 1k   $$

Now it comes

$\underline{n= k+1:}$ $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1{i^2} + \frac 1{(k+1)^2} \lt 2- \frac 1k + \frac1{(k+1)^2}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1{(i+1)^2} \lt 2 - \frac {(k+1)^2 + k} {k(k+1)^2}= \frac{2k(k+1)^2 - (k+1)^2 + k }{k(k+1)^2} $$

Am I right working in the right direction and could someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: You can't prove what is wrong...

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac1{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}6$

Comment: sorry I will edit it

Comment: I meant to write an inequality but somehow I started with an equation. My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}  
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2}+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}< 2-\frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} 
= 2- \frac{n^2+n+\color{orange}{1}}{n(n+1)^2} 
< 2 - \frac{n^2+n}{n(n+1)^2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Yellow on white is a rather suboptimal typographical choice, IMO.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I want to covey the idea to ignore this term. Lets try orange ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit That much was clear. It was the number itself to be almost invisible.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit How do you come up with latter inequality? Is one allowed to neglect the 1 so that one gets an inequality?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}  
\color{orange}{- \frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} 
< 0} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So 
\begin{eqnarray*}  
2-\frac{n^2+n}{n(n+1)^2} \color{orange}{- \frac{1}{n(n+1)^2}} 
< 2-\frac{n^2+n}{n(n+1)^2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative approach, not by induction, and is posted for information only.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac 1{r^2}\;
&<\;1+\int_1^n\frac 1{x^2} dx
&&=1+\left[-\frac 1x\right]_1^n\\
& &&=1+\left(-\frac 1n+1\right)\\
& &&=2-\frac 1n\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \sum_{k=\color{red}{2}}^n \dfrac1{k^2}
&<& \displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^n \dfrac1{k(k-1)} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\dfrac1{k-1} - \dfrac1k\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac11-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n \\
&=& \displaystyle 1-\frac1n \\
\displaystyle \sum_{k=\color{red}{1}}^n \dfrac1{k^2}
&<& \displaystyle \frac1{1^2}+1-\frac1n \\
&=& \displaystyle 2-\frac1n
\end{array}$$

Use this as a basis of your induction.

Comment: Ok, I will use it. As soon as I'm ready I'll post an answer. Can you verify that later?

Comment: @AnonymousI ok.

Comment: You made use of telescopic sum, didn't you? What is your argument to use this expression for the continuation of the proof?

Comment: Induction, which I leave to you :)

Comment: Touché you got me there.